# "Blending out" noise in images?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I don't know if there is an official name for this.

I am trying to do some color analysis on a picture using Python on the pixel-level, but the problem is that sometimes there are little bits of pixels here and there that might have wildly different colors and mess up the analysis.

Is there a way to "smooth the picture out" so these little irregularities go away and the colors are more uniformly distributed within their respective regions?

Comment: Sounds like you want a median filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`MedianFilter`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.MedianFilter) in the [`ImageFilter`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html) module.

```
corrected_image = original_image.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter(7))
```

You'll probably want to adjust the filter size. (I've set it to `7` here.)

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!